# Calculate CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) for HEX string

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc, crc32

I'm trying to calulate CRC-CCITT (0xFFFF) for HEX string and get result back as HEX string. I tried `binascii` and `crc16` but I get int values and when I convert them to HEX it's not the value I expected. I need this:

```
hex_string = "AA01"
crc_string = crccitt(hex_string)
print("CRC: ", crc_string)

>>> CRC: FF9B
```

Comment: Is that literal `"AA01"` or hex `0xaa01`?

Comment: I used this online calculator. http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html
I'm trying to send that over UDP. So, I convert strings using `b16decode(hex_string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) / [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) to convert the int value to hexadecimal format: (used [`crc16`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crc16) to get crc)

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import crc16
>>> hex_string = 'AA01'
>>> crc = crc16.crc16xmodem(binascii.unhexlify(hex_string), 0xffff)
>>> '{:04X}'.format(crc & 0xffff)
'FF9B'
>>> format(crc & 0xffff, '04X')
'FF9B'
```

or using [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
>>> '%04X' % (crc & 0xffff)
'FF9B'
```

---

```
import binascii
import crc16

def crccitt(hex_string):
    byte_seq = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)
    crc = crc16.crc16xmodem(byte_seq, 0xffff)
    return '{:04X}'.format(crc & 0xffff)
```